# Find the solution of the recurrence relation $a_n=4a_{n-1}-3a_{n-2}+2^n+n+3$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Using the characteristic equation $r^2=4r-3 \to r^2-4r+3=(r-3)(r-1)$ results in roots $1,3$. I show that $a_n^{(h)}=\alpha_1+\alpha_23^n$

I'm having a hard time understanding how to handle the non-homogenous part of this relation, I thought maybe I could break it into 2 parts as follows, but I'm not sure if this is correct:
$$a_n^{(p1)}=c\cdot2^n=4c\cdot2^{n-1}-3c\cdot2^{n-2}+2^n$$
$$c\cdot2^2=4c\cdot2^1-3c+2^2$$
$$c=-4$$
$$a_n^{(p1)}=(-4)\cdot2^n$$
Since $1$ is a root, $F(n)=(n+3)1^n=n(np_1+p_0)$
$$a_n^{(p2)}=n^2p_1+np_0=4((n-1)^2p_1+(n-1)p_0)-3((n-2)^2p_1+(n-2)p_0)+n+3$$
$$n^2p_1+np_0=4(n^2p_1-2np_1+p_1+np_0-p_0)-3(n^2p_1-4np_1+4p_1+np_0+-2p_0)+n+3$$
$$0=-8np_1+12np_1+n+4p_1-12p_1-4p_0+6p_0+3$$
$$n(4p_1+1)+(3-8p_1+2p_0)$$
Solving for $p_1=-\frac{1}{4}$, $p_0=-\frac{5}{2}$

Therefore $a_n=a_n^{(h)}+a_n^{(p1)}+a_n^{(p2)}$?
$$a_n=\alpha+\alpha_23^n-4\cdot2^n-n(\frac{n}{4}+\frac{5}{2})$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3176593/consider-the-non-homogeneous-linear-recurrence-relations-a-n-2a-n-12n-find/3177144#3177144

Comment: @labbhattacharjeethe $n+3$ portion is what I'm struggling with...

Comment: $$a_n=b_n+2^n(a_0+a_1n+\cdots)+b_0+b_1n+\cdots$$

Comment: Thanks I updated the question, and believe I was able to work it out. I needed to modify $a_n^{(p2)}$ to account for 1 existing as a root in the homogeneous equation.

Answer (score 1):

At first solve the homogeneous equation $$a_n=4a_{n-1}-3a_{n-2}$$ by the ansatz $$a_n=q^n$$

Comment: I can add that to the question... I have $a_n^{(h)}=\alpha_1+\alpha_23^n$

Comment: This is right, and the inhomogeneous equation? You will need a particular solution.

Comment: Correct, this is where I'm stuck, I'm not sure what to guess when $F(n)=2^n+n+3$, I tried $F(n)=F_1(n)+F_2(n)$, when $F_1(n)=2^n$, and $F_2(n)=n+3$

Comment: I have got $$-\frac{1}{4}n(n+8)-2^{n+2}-\frac{9}{8}$$

Comment: Could you share the characteristic equation you started with?